# Adjoint of the differential in Morse-Novikov cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, adjoint-operators, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold and we can define the Morse-Novikov cohomology group $H^k (M^n,\theta)$ with co-boundary differential operator $d_\theta (w) = dw + \theta \wedge w$  where $0\neq[\theta]∈ H_{dR}^1(M^n)$. This cohomology shares many properties with the ordinary de Rham cohomology and only depend on $[\theta]$.

As it has been shown that the Hodge theory works nicely on this cohomology by defining the adjoint operator $d_\theta^*$ ( I suppose it defines as usual adjoint $\delta$ of de Rham operator $d$ ) and defining the corresponding Laplacian of these operators.

I have the following question: It seems to me that the Stokes’ theorem does not work well with this operator $d_\theta$ because we will have an extra  term which is $\int_M[\theta \wedge w]$and this implies that the Green formula will not work (i.e. $d_\theta^*$ will no longer be adjoint of $d_\theta$). Am I right?

Comment: In your second paragraph you're using $d_{\theta}^*$ to denote the adjoint of $d_{\theta}$, but in the third paragraph, you suggest $d_{\theta}^*$ isn't the adjoint. You seem to mean two different things by adjoint in these paragraphs. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The second paragraph refers to which you can see in the literature review when you read about the relation between this Cohomology and Hogde decomposition where they used to state this statement (it seems direct because it repeated in different references). Is it clear now? However, the third paragraph was my question: I see that Stokes’ theorem does not work well with this operator $d_\theta$ and then this implies $d_\theta^*$ will no longer be adjoint of $d_\theta$ so I do not understand what exist in the literature review and what I infer from Stokes’ theorem. I am sorry about that

Comment: How are you (or the references you refer to) defining $d_{\theta}^*$?

Comment: of course not me, see for instance this paper (MORSE-NOVIKOV COHOMOLOGY OF LOCALLY CONFORMALLY K¨AHLER SURFACES) it refers to $d_\theta$ by $\delta_\theta$

Comment: The operator defined in that paper is indeed the adjoint of $d_{\theta}$ (when $n$ is even, which is the case in Otiman's paper). The fact that $\int_Md_{\theta}\omega \neq 0$ has no bearing on this.

Answer (score 3):

In the paper mentioned in the comments, the operator $d_{\theta}$ is slightly different than the one you mention in your question: $d_{\theta}(w) = dw - \theta\wedge w$. In addition, the operator $\delta_{\theta}$ is defined as $-\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$. In that paper, Otiman is concerned with Inoue surfaces which have real dimension four. In even dimensions, the expression $-\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$ is indeed the adjoint of $d_{\theta}$. In odd dimensions, the adjoint is given by $(-1)^{n(k-1)+1}\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$ when acting on $k$-forms.

To see this, let $\alpha \in \Omega^{k-1}(M)$ and $\beta \in \Omega^k(M)$, then

$$\langle d_{\theta}\alpha, \beta\rangle = \langle d\alpha - \theta\wedge\alpha, \beta\rangle = \langle d\alpha, \beta\rangle - \langle\theta\wedge\alpha, \beta\rangle = \langle\alpha, d^*\beta\rangle - \langle\theta\wedge\alpha, \beta\rangle.$$

Now note that

\begin{align*}
\langle\theta\wedge\alpha, \beta\rangle &= \int_M\theta\wedge\alpha\wedge\ast\beta\\ 
&= \int_M(-1)^{k-1}\alpha\wedge\theta\wedge\ast\beta\\ 
&= \int_M(-1)^{k-1}\alpha\wedge(-1)^{(n-k+1)(k-1)}\ast\ast(\theta\wedge\ast\beta)\\ 
&= (-1)^{(n-k)(k-1)}\int_M\alpha\wedge\ast\ast(\theta\wedge\ast\beta)\\ 
&= \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)}\ast(\theta\wedge\ast\beta)\rangle.
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
\langle d_{\theta}\alpha, \beta\rangle &= \langle\alpha, d^*\beta\rangle - \langle\theta\wedge\alpha, \beta\rangle\\ 
&= \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)+1}\ast d\ast\beta\rangle - \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)}\ast(\theta\wedge\ast\beta)\rangle\\ 
&= \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)+1}[\ast d\ast \beta + \ast(\theta\wedge\ast\beta)]\rangle\\
&= \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)+1}\ast[d(\ast\beta) + \theta\wedge(\ast\beta)]\rangle\\
&= \langle\alpha, (-1)^{n(k-1)+1}\ast d_{-\theta}(\ast\beta)\rangle
\end{align*}

so the adjoint of $d_{\theta} : \Omega^{k-1}(M) \to \Omega^k(M)$ is $(-1)^{n(k-1)+1}\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$. If $n$ is even, this reduces to $-\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$ (the operator Otiman calls $\delta_{\theta}$), and if $n$ is odd, this reduces to $(-1)^k\ast d_{-\theta}\ast$.

Comment: thanks so much for your kind answer

Comment: The operator $−∗d_{(−1)^k\theta}\ ∗$ cannot be the adjoint of $d_\theta$, since its square is not zero. The error in the computation is that the adjoint of $d$ is not $−∗d∗$, but $(−1)^{n(k−1)+1}∗d∗$.

Comment: @IvanYudin: Thanks for pointing this out, I have edited accordingly.